# What safeguards are taken when a login system only requires a PIN and no username?

Tags: authentication

The gym I go to gives its customers access to the building by giving them a 6 digit PIN code which they must type in on a keypad when they want to enter/exit the gym.

- Does the person who was added onto the system straight after me receive `my_pin + 1` ? Eventually, will somebody get `my_pin + 1` ? Isn't this a poorly designed system?
- What happens when the gym has 999999 customers?

(*I am only asking this because I am curious - I already have a PIN - I don't need another one :) )*

Comment: How could _anyone_ answer that ? Ask these questions to your gym manager

Comment: I am a customer, I don't work there. I am just curious, *in general*, what safeguards are taken in a situation like this.

Comment: Your questions are not about anything general. You're asking about a specific system that nobody here has any knowledge of or access to.

Comment: So? What's stopping an experienced user to apply their knowledge as to what *could* be happening? I just want an insight - the title of my question is about *a* system - I just gave an example of that in my description.

Comment: @PPG I think the issue that Stephane is bringing up is that you're asking what safeguards are done for a system, instead of what safeguards are done for a system *with a given threat model*.  **There literally is no answer to this question which isn't a valid answer!**  Everyone might have the same pin, or everyone might get random pins, or everyone might get sequential pins, there might be a lockout if you fail too many times, there may be a security camera watching the pin reader, pins may change... the list goes on and on, and without a threat model we can't narrow it down.

Comment: Oh my favorite: there might be two very scary looking federal officers standing on opposite sides of the PIN reader, right hands suspiciously close to the pistols slung low on their waste, each sporting an earpiece to listen to commands from some unseen headquarters.  Do you have *any* idea how hard it is to remember your 6 digit PIN in that scenario? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

1) Not necessarily. There are a lot of ways to generate random integers in a prescribed range (say, 000000 to 999999) so that if your pin is `my_pin`, the next user may have a completely unrelated `other_pin`. As for "will somebody get `my_pin+1`?", it depends on the maximum number of simultaneous customers (i.e. of PINs valid in the same timeframe), which brings us to your next question.

2) On one hand, unless your gym is extremely large, it will never have more than a million users per subscription year/month/semester. For example, if it can have 1,000 customers at most, the system may be able to generate 1,000 random integers in the range 000000 to 999999. Even if, within the 10,20, or more years of activity of your gym, it may actually count a million users, this is not a problem, because the PIN code doesn't need to be valid forever. This means that it would be pretty easy to reset the PIN generation at the beginning of a new membership period. Things get a bit more complex if you can subscribe at any given time, but it could still be done. If this couldn't be done, they could widen the range to, say, 9999999.

On the other hand: what would happen if two customers had the same PIN? It depends. If the only purpose of the PIN is to check that the person entering the gym is a real customer, nothing significant would happen. However, you need to consider that this system would allow your friends to use the resources of the gym, provided you give them your PIN, and this may not be in the interests of the owners. So, basically, the whole system (regardless of the PIN generation method) would be flawed, unless another "authentication system" was used, such as a receptionist checking that strangers are not entering the gym.

If the PIN was somehow related to personal discounts, someone could be able to obtain a discount which was actually addressed to you.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the system was configured by your gym. It would definitely not be secure if it was your_pin + 1, cause then then you quit the gym, you could easily still get in. I imagine they have a formula to assign pins randomly without duplicating them. Once the gym hits over 999999 customers (which they probably wont), either they start assigning pins to two people (which means you would be unable to identify who it is) and would be a really bad idea OR they increase it to a 7 digit pin. Its hard to tell for sure what they did, it really depends on who set it up and what they believe is a good idea or if they even thought about security while setting it up.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: **way** too broad of a question. Even by imagining scenarios, anything could be happening. We sometimes answer general questions on what **could** happen, but this is a bit too much.

- Who knows? I don't think any of us is the gym owner here, so we couldn't possibly know how the system works. Maybe everyone gets the same pin, for all we know.
  Even if the pins are unique and perfectly randomized, then yes, there's a chance that someone got your_pin+1 (chance depending on whether you can pick the same pin again or not, etc.)
- Again, depends on the system. All 999999 members could have the same pin, or every possible number could end up being a working pin.

Just so this question can get any useful: **there isn't any absolutely poorly 
designed system**. This is all relative: proper security management **must** match the system, the needs and the context, and thus requires a proper **risk analysis**. You can't know if a system is badly designed or not without having any clue on what's at stake.

For example, you could:

- Require the gym member to log in on a website through SSL and get the first part of his code here. The website would of course have been audited for classic SQL/XSS/CSRF and software-related vulnerabilities.
- Then the second part of the code would arrive via SMS on the user's phone
- The third part comes via a letter on the address you gave him
- The fourth part is given directly by the gym owner after he has confirmed your prints and face match his records

You would then arrive in front of the gym where a keyboard awaits you, and where you have to type your 60-character password.

Would this be secure? Sure. Is this needed? You tell me.